# Integrating Rich Calendar with Joda Time

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, jodatime

I am looking to use the Rich:Calendar in my JSF app. I am planning to use the CalendarDataModel to restrict selection of some dates like weekends, holidays etc. The date format that we use is based on Joda Time.

The issue is that the Rich:Calendar is based on JDK Calendar, so i am thinking to use the JDK Calendar for the display and convert the date to jodatime later when it is persisted.

Has anyone used Rich:Calendar/Joda Time for selecting a date with the calendardatamodel, could you share your valuable thoughts. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom FacesConverter to enable jodatime-objects in rich:calendar, no need to use JDK Calendar.
Just specify the converter in rich:calendar, and implement the two methods of the Converter interface (se example using LocalDate).

**JSF w/Richfaces 4.2**

```
<rich:calendar value="#{myObject.myLocalDate}" datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy" converter="localDateConverter"/>
```

**Your converter-class:**

```
@FacesConverter(value = "localDateConverter")
public class LocalDateConverter implements Converter {
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String localDateInTextFormat) {
        return DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy").parseLocalDate(localDateInTextFormat);
    }
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object localDate) {
        return DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy").print((LocalDate)localDate);
    }
}
```